# How to copy text to clipboard in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, text, onclick

I would like to integrate a small text (my e-mail address) but I would like the user can to copy this text. I think of a button, when we click on it the e-mail address is copied and it can be pasted outside the app. How to do this?

```js
<View>
<Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 14 , fontFamily:'Arial', fontStyle: 'bold', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 3, marginLeft: 25, marginBottom: 17}}> 
             mail@mail.com
</Text></View>
```

I am a novice, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use [`Clipboard` from @react-native-community](https://github.com/react-native-clipboard/clipboard#react-native-communityclipboard).

Here's how you can use it:

```
import Clipboard from '@react-native-clipboard/clipboard';

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Clipboard.setString('mail@mail.com')}>
  <View>
    <Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 14 , fontFamily:'Arial', fontStyle: 'bold', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 3, marginLeft: 25, marginBottom: 17}}> 
                mail@mail.com
    </Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: thanks but I have an error, I think it must come from touchable opacity?

Comment: ReferenceError: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TouchableOpacity

Comment: I have edited my answer don't forget to import the `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: Clipboard has been removed from react-native core and should be installed from `@react-native-community/clipboard`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with expo, so I added an answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72171868/1121497

Comment: You must import `import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'` or can use `import { Pressable } from 'react-native'`

Answer (score 32):

Set selectable prop of the Text component true and the content will be copied to the clipboard with long press on the text.

```js
<Text selectable={true}>
  Your text
</Text>
```

Comment: This is not the correct solution for above issue. But this is a general good solution, if you need a piece of text that needs to be able to be copied from.

Answer (score 9):

Since I guess may people use [expo](https://expo.dev/), you need another lib there.

```sh
expo install expo-clipboard
```

```js
import * as Clipboard from 'expo-clipboard';

// Then just do like in the accepted solution:
Clipboard.setString('mail@mail.com');
```

Solution taken from:
https://github.com/react-native-clipboard/clipboard/issues/110#issuecomment-931340618

Comment: Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoClipboard'

Comment: This is not woking with expo

Comment: setString() is deprecated. Use setStringAsync()

Answer (score 4):

`import { Button, Clipboard } from 'react-native'`
is replace with    [`react-native-community/clipboard`](https://github.com/react-native-community/clipboard#readme)

Comment: The official `Clipboard` is deprecated. Now you should use the community lib.

Answer (score 1):

fayeed is right. You can use clipboard for user to copy a string.

Also, you easily give your  component a clipboard too. As fayeed did above

```
<Text 
onPress={()=>Clipboard.setString('mail@mail.com')}
style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 14 , fontFamily:'Arial', fontStyle: 'bold', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 3, marginLeft: 25, marginBottom: 17}}> 
                mail@mail.com
    </Text>
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Apparently outdated, see comment and top answer.

---

So, you managed to get your text on the screen using `Text`, and now you want the user to be able to copy it; I can imagine three ways of doing this:

- How to make text selectable (and copyable) in react-native?
- How to show "copy popover" in react-native?
- How to copy text to clipboard on button tap in react-native?

Let's focus on the last one. We can break it down further:

- How to make a button in react-native?
- How to execute a function on button tap? (in react-native)
- How to copy text to clipboard programatically? (in react-native)

If we google these phrases, we find the relevant documentation:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/clipboard

...with the relevant piece of code:

```
import { Button, Clipboard } from 'react-native'
...
const email = 'hello@example.com'
const copyIt = ()=> Clipboard.setString(email)
...
<Button
  onPress={copyIt}
  title={email}
/>
```

Comment: Clipboard from 'react-native' is deprecated. We should use the community package instead: `@react-native-clipboard/clipboard`